# Implementing parts of an array of one method into a new method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have a project and I have to find data based on a given month year or day. If null, it returns data for all that year/day/month. I got the first method to read the file and put the data into an array; each line being data for a specific time in the format of

# site_code year month day hour minute second value value_unc nvalue latitude longitude altitude elevation intake_height instrument qcflag

An example of data strings being:

> BRW 1973 1 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..
>
> BRW 1973 1 2 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

The problem is, I don't know how to get parts of the first method array in order to gather all the data of called year/day/month.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<CO2Data> loadData(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    String input = "";
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
         while ((input = scan.next()) != null){
        input = scan.next();
        if (input == "BRW"){
            array.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }

    return array;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<CO2Data> getData(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day) {

    ArrayList array = null;
    for(int i = 0;  != null; i++){
        if (year == nextLoadData || year == null){
        if (month == nextLoadData || month == null){
        if (day == nextLoadData || day == null){
        array.add();
        }}
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: The statement "I don't know how to get parts of the first method array" is very ambiguous. Can you explain what you mean by the first method array? Do you mean the first array in your method? There are no arrays in either of your methods. Do you mean the list called `array`? If so, what do you mean by getting the parts of the list?

Comment: i want to grab lines of data from the first method arraylist that was returned in the first method and compare them in the second method to return all relating lines

Comment: What do you mean by 'grab lines of data'? You need to be more specific. Do you want to create `CO2Data` objects from the strings you are reading?

Comment: i want to use the strings of data from the first method array list in the second method. These strings contain data based on times such as in the exampleBRW 1973 1 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *.. I need to compare the year/day/month within said string and return an array list with all the strings from the first method that match the parameters of the second method

Comment: Ah ok. I think you have some design issues you need to address. I'll provide an answer giving you some hints on how to progress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add the full solution so you can study and change it.

First, we have the class CO2Data to hold one single line of data. Maybe you could check [Lesson: Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

### CO2Data:

```
public class CO2Data
{
    private String site_code;
    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;
    private String hour;
    private String minute;
    private String second;
    private String value;
    private String value_unc;
    private String nvalue;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String altitude;
    private String elevation;
    private String intake_height;
    private String instrument;
    private String qcflag;

    public CO2Data(){

    }

    public String getSite_code ( )
    {
        return site_code;
    }
    public void setSite_code ( String site_code )
    {
        this.site_code = site_code;
    }
    public String getYear ( )
    {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear ( String year )
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getMonth ( )
    {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth ( String month )
    {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public String getDay ( )
    {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay ( String day )
    {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public String getHour ( )
    {
        return hour;
    }
    public void setHour ( String hour )
    {
        this.hour = hour;
    }
    public String getMinute ( )
    {
        return minute;
    }
    public void setMinute ( String minute )
    {
        this.minute = minute;
    }
    public String getSecond ( )
    {
        return second;
    }
    public void setSecond ( String second )
    {
        this.second = second;
    }
    public String getValue ( )
    {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue ( String value )
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue_unc ( )
    {
        return value_unc;
    }
    public void setValue_unc ( String value_unc )
    {
        this.value_unc = value_unc;
    }
    public String getNvalue ( )
    {
        return nvalue;
    }
    public void setNvalue ( String nvalue )
    {
        this.nvalue = nvalue;
    }
    public String getLatitude ( )
    {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude ( String latitude )
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude ( )
    {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude ( String longitude )
    {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String getAltitude ( )
    {
        return altitude;
    }
    public void setAltitude ( String altitude )
    {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }
    public String getElevation ( )
    {
        return elevation;
    }
    public void setElevation ( String elevation )
    {
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }
    public String getIntake_height ( )
    {
        return intake_height;
    }
    public void setIntake_height ( String intake_height )
    {
        this.intake_height = intake_height;
    }
    public String getInstrument ( )
    {
        return instrument;
    }
    public void setInstrument ( String instrument )
    {
        this.instrument = instrument;
    }
    public String getQcflag ( )
    {
        return qcflag;
    }
    public void setQcflag ( String qcflag )
    {
        this.qcflag = qcflag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "CO2Data [site_code="    + site_code + ", year=" + year + ", month=" + month + ", day="
                + day + ", hour=" + hour + ", minute=" + minute + ", second=" + second + ", value="
                + value + ", value_unc=" + value_unc + ", nvalue=" + nvalue + ", latitude="
                + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + ", altitude=" + altitude + ", elevation="
                + elevation + ", intake_height=" + intake_height + ", instrument=" + instrument
                + ", qcflag=" + qcflag + "]";
    }



}
```

### MainClass with methods implemented:

> 1) read data from the file and save it on a CO2Data List.
>
> 2) get data from the previous list matching the results.
>
> 3) print :D
>
> Note: Do not forget to change **PathToFile** with yours.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {

        List<CO2Data> readList = loadData ( "PathToFile" );
        if ( readList != null )
        {
            List<CO2Data> dataFound = getData ( readList , "1973" , "1" , "1" );

            if( dataFound != null )
            {
                //separator
                System.out.println ( "----------------------------------------" );

                //print results
                for(int i = 0; i < dataFound.size ( ); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println ( dataFound.get ( i ).toString ( ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Read data from the file
    public static List<CO2Data> loadData(String filename)
    {

        List<CO2Data> listCO2Data = new ArrayList < CO2Data >( );
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (scan.hasNextLine ( ))
            {
                CO2Data data = new CO2Data ( );
                data.setSite_code(scan.next());
                data.setYear(scan.next());
                data.setMonth(scan.next());
                data.setDay(scan.next());
                data.setHour(scan.next());
                data.setMinute(scan.next());
                data.setSecond(scan.next());
                data.setValue(scan.next());
                data.setValue_unc(scan.next());
                data.setNvalue(scan.next());
                data.setLatitude(scan.next());
                data.setLongitude(scan.next());
                data.setAltitude(scan.next());
                data.setElevation(scan.next());
                data.setIntake_height(scan.next());
                data.setInstrument(scan.next());
                data.setQcflag(scan.next());
                //print adds just for informational purposes
                System.out.println ( data.toString ( ) );
                listCO2Data.add ( data );
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace ( );
            System.out.println("Could not find file");
        }

        return listCO2Data.isEmpty ( ) ? null : listCO2Data;
    }

    //get data with matching dates
    public static List < CO2Data > getData(List<CO2Data> data, String year, String month, String day) 
    {
        List < CO2Data > dataFound = new ArrayList<> ( );

        for(CO2Data current : data)
        {
            if( current.getYear ( ).equals ( year ) &&
                    current.getMonth ( ).equals ( month ) &&
                    current.getDay ( ).equals ( day ))
            {
                dataFound.add ( current );
            }
        }
        return dataFound.isEmpty ( ) ? null : dataFound ;
    }
}
```

### Input.txt:

```
BRW 1973 1 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

BRW 1973 2 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

BRW 1973 3 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

BRW 1973 4 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

BRW 1973 5 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..

BRW 1973 1 1 0 0 0 -999.99 -99.99 0 71.323 -156.611 27.0 11.0 16.0 NA *..
```

### Output:

```
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=2, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=3, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=4, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=5, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
----------------------------------------
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
CO2Data [site_code=BRW, year=1973, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, value=-999.99, value_unc=-99.99, nvalue=0, latitude=71.323, longitude=-156.611, altitude=27.0, elevation=11.0, intake_height=16.0, instrument=NA, qcflag=*..]
```

I also added some comments in the code.
If you have any question about the code do not hesitate on ask and i will edit my answer accordingly.
Good luck.

Comment: Ok this code makes a lot of sense and follows the class implementation, however the CO2Data class doesn't give me setters/accessors but rather --public CO2Data(
       String site_code,
       int year,
       int month,
       int day         int hour,
         int minute,
         int second,
         double value,
         double valueUnc,
         int nvalue,
         double latitude,
         double altitude,
         double elevation,
      this.site_code = site_code;
      this.year----- etc. to use

Comment: That is the constructor of your class. You should do something like `CO2Data( scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextEtc... )` instead of set every attribute. and if you have no getters, you should `@override equals` to evaluate just by **YYYY/MM/DD**

Comment: I can't make the data variables strings cause I also need to find averages for given years, so if the given CO2Data class has variables initialized in ints/doubles/strings, how can I get those into the main class without getters and setters

Comment: I cannot infer how you CO2Data class looks like, could you please attach your class, so i can make a more elaborated answer?. Also the attributes doesn't have to be String.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to do some redesign here to make things easier for yourself. I'll make some suggestions and you can let me know in comments if you are having trouble understanding.

You already have a `CO2Data` class that, presumably, stores the information from a single line of your file. Ideally it would have a method that can take an input string and convert to one of these objects. Let's assume it looks something like:

```
class CO2Data {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\s{3}) (\\d{4})");

    private final String siteCode;
    private final LocalDataTime timeOfReading;

    private CO2Data(String siteCode, int year) {
        this.siteCode = siteCode;
        this.timeOfReading = LocalDataTime.of(year, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    public static CO2Data createFromLine(String line) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.match(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String siteCode = matcher.group(1);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            return new CO2Data(siteCode, year);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrectly formatted line");
        }
    }
}
```

I've simplified it down to site code and year for clarity but you can extend to the other fields fairly trivially.

Your method that reads from the file should return a list of these objects:

```
public List<CO2Data> getDataFromFile(Path filepath) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(filepath)
        .map(CO2Data::createFromLine)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then your method that filters by year and month can take a list of these objects:

```
public List<CO2Data> search(List<CO2Data> list, Integer year) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(d -> year == null || d.getTime().getYear() == year)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that I've used Java 8 features here.

Comment: Maybe this is too much difficult to understand for the OP. My solution is more simple, but this is definitely more elegant.

Comment: @Thrasher you might be right. Streams are still fairly new.